# I got error from calling json() when trying to running

Tags: pandas, streamlit

Hello i want asking somethin that i got when i tried to run my streamlit, so i got error like this on my frontend page, i import it from backend page:
[image]

i will show my code too

```
Predict = st.button('Predict Satisfacion Rate')


if Predict:
        r = requests.post(URL, json=data)
        res = r.json()

if res['code'] == 200:
    res2 =  (res['result']['description'])
    if res2 == 'Not Satisfied':
        st.markdown('**The Passenger is not Satisfied**')
        col4,col5,col6 = st.columns([1,1,1])
        with col5 :
            st.image('Happy.jpg')
    
    else:
        st.markdown('**The Passenger is Satisfied**')
        col7,col8,col9 = st.columns([1,1,1])
        with col8 :
            st.image('NotHappy.jpg')
else:
    st.write('**Error**')
    st.write(f"Details : {res['result']['description']}")
```

so how can i do to solve this error?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the conversion `res = r.json()` is unnecessary. Unless you really need this as JSON somewhere else, you can test the status code directly from the `r` object as `r.status_code`.

After `if r.status_code == 200:`, you can then convert to JSON if you really need to, as you should be confident that the server returned a valid response.

Comment: so i used this Jsontify add backend file so i recall it on frontend page sir